# TMC5160 Overheating

Tags: stepper-driver, arduino

I am trying to do a project using stepsticks to drive stepper motors. I am currently testing the wiring of stepsticks on a breadboard using a stepper from CD driver and an old laptop charger. I connected it to my old A4988 driver according to this wiring diagram and everything is working how it should.

[image: A4988 connection]

However, when I tried to swap the driver for the new TMC5160, and use it in STEP/DIR mode, the driver didn't work and one driving MOSFET started to overheat.

My question is what am I doing wrong and is there anything I need to wire up differently? Or is the driver fried?

Before anyone asks I disconnected the power supply and arduino and I double checked the orientation of the driver not to connect it upside down.